# Configuring Nuxeo CMF at Localhost for Customization of Nuxeo CMF interface

Tags: configuration, customization, case, nuxeo

When I tried to start the Nuxeo CMF server after setting "nuxeo.force.generation=false" in "nuxeo.conf" file, it shows like you should either set it to "true" or "once" or otherwise set "nuxeo.wizard.done=true". If we set it to true, the changes will be lost. What will happen if we set it to "once" or otherwise by setting "nuxeo.wizard.done=true". I want to make the changes permanent to the Nuxeo CMF interface.

Thanks & Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What changes do you want to keep? 
If you want to customize some files (such as contributions in `nxserver/config/`), then you have to use [the configuration templates](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/0AB9) and [create a custom configuration template](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/LANc).
If you want to customize, for instance, some files in nuxeo.war, then you have to [create a Nuxeo bundle](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/kwBu).